# Accessing the default JDBC database in Play for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

[In this Play tutorial](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase) it is explained how to use a JDBC connection pool, including an example to access the database. Problem is that it is not clear how to assign the default database to the `db` field.

For example:

```
class ScalaControllerInject @Inject() extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    var outString = "Number is "

    val db: Database = ??? // How to assign the default database to db?

    val conn = db.getConnection()

    try {
      val stmt = conn.createStatement
      val rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT 9 as testkey ")

      while (rs.next()) {
        outString += rs.getString("testkey")
      }
    } finally {
      conn.close()
    }
    Ok(outString)
  }

}
```

I put the db declaration in the method instead of the class parameter, but the intent is the same.

Note: I'm using Play 2.5.2

Comment: The example shows that you can have it injected. Look at this line `class ScalaControllerInject @Inject()(db: Database) extends Controller`

Comment: Problem is that if I instantiate the class with `val x = new ScalaControllerInject()` it throws an error saying that I need to specify the `Database` as a parameter, and I don't know what to put in the parameter.

Comment: Why would you instantiate this class? Guice will create it and provide all dependencies.

Comment: thanks, I figured it out now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you have a look at the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaDatabase), you can see how to inject the default DB (configured in `application.conf`) in your controller.

```
import javax.inject.Inject

import play.api.Play.current
import play.api.mvc._
import play.api.db._

class ScalaControllerInject @Inject()(db: Database) extends Controller {
  // ...
}
```

Take care to the class declaration, where `@Inject()` is followed by the list of injected arguments.

Then the `db` instance can be used in the actions.

```
db.withConnection { con: java.sql.Connection =>
  doSomethingWith(con)
}
```

If you configure more than one DB in the application settings, the `NamedDatabase` annotation can be used inject the proper one.

import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.db.{ Database, NamedDatabase }
import play.api.mvc.Controller

```
// inject "orders" database instead of "default"
class ScalaInjectNamed @Inject()(
  @NamedDatabase("orders") db: Database) extends Controller {

  // do whatever you need with the db
}
```

Comment: does the @Inject only work with a controller? What if I want to use my database in a non-controller class? `class WorksWithDB( db : Database) { ... } ` Then when I create an instance of that class, I have to feed it an instance of the database, whether or not there's an @Inject() in front of the constructor or not.

Comment: It works for what's managed by the DI engine. Have a look at the related docs

Comment: I've gone through a bunch of them, but I guess what I'm asking, is there a way to get at your application's default database from a class without injecting it?

Comment: Only components loaded by the DI can be injected with dependencies in this way: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/ScalaDependencyInjection#How-it-works

Answer (score 1):

I found what I was looking for in the conversation being had in the accepted answer's comments. You can also get a connection to a database this way, if you don't want to use injection. Your SBT .build must be configured to the database you have and the proper JDBC driver. But, if you have that, then in whatever class you want to use the data base, be sure you have:

`import play.api.db.Databases`

and then you can:

```
class ExampleClass {

  val testDb = Databases(
    driver = "org.postgresql.Driver",
    url = "postgres://dbUserName:password@localhost:port#/name_of_db"
  )
```

And this will allow you to use the `testDb` object as you would otherwise.